# Get a list of the webparts on a page

Tags: web-part

Is there somewhere you can view a list of all webparts embedded on a specific page?

I have taken over development of a SharePoint website and some pages have a ton of webparts, and I have no way of knowing the name of each webpart so that I can go in and modify them.

Cheers

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can add **?contents=1** to the current page url to view a 'web parts maintenance page'. From there you should be able to see the web parts on the page, the type, and if they're open or closed.

Comment: Thanks @glynClough
Is there a way where i can get their GUIDs?

Please share your thoughts
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/146315/get-the-list-of-all-webparts-ids-in-a-page

Answer (score 2):

When using the SharePoint object model you can get a webpartcollection using the webpartmanager.
This has a "WebParts" property which returns a webpartcollection.
Here you can get all the webparts properties.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpartmanager.aspx