# Get the list of all webparts IDs in a page using REST/CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, content-editor-web-part

I have few content editor web parts in my page

I need to get the GUID of all the web parts that are there in the page

I am able to get the list of all webparts in the page by navigating to

```
http://pageurl?content=1
```

I couldnt find the GUID's of the webparts, how can i get them using REST/CSOM or any other client side method?

Answer (score 4):

**Using JSOM**

```
 var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
    var oFile = clientContext.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(_spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath);
    var limitedWebPartManager = oFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
    var collWebPart = limitedWebPartManager.get_webParts();

    clientContext.load(collWebPart);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
        var webPartDef = null;
        for (var x = 0; x < collWebPart.get_count() && !webPartDef; x++) {
            var temp = collWebPart.get_item(x);
            if (temp.get_id().toString() === wpId) {
                webPartDef = temp;
            }
        }
        if (!webPartDef) {
            dfd.reject("Web Part: " + wpId + " not found on page: " + _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
            return;
        }

        var webPartProperties = webPartDef.get_webPart().get_properties();
        clientContext.load(webPartProperties);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
            dfd.resolve(webPartProperties, webPartDef, clientContext);
        }), Function.createDelegate(this, function () { dfd.reject("Failed to load web part properties"); }));
    }), Function.createDelegate(this, function () { dfd.reject("Failed to load web part collection"); }));

    return dfd.promise();
}
```

http://dluat.com/reasonable-way-to-get-custom-webpart-properties-via-jsom/

**Using REST**

```
_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/test/Home.aspx')/GetLimitedWebPartManager(scope=1)/WebParts?$expand=WebPart&$filter=WebPart/Title+eq+'Test'
```

You can get webpartcollection using the `webpartmanager.WebPartManager` control acts as the hub or control center of a Web Parts application.

There must be one and only one [WebPartManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpartmanager.aspx) control instance on **every page** that uses Web Parts controls.

Comment: Thanks Amit
Anyway that can be done via clientside code?

Comment: See my edited answer

Comment: Thanks Amit, upvoted
Will try this out :)