# How to remove webpart from page when page is broken

Tags: 2016, migration, sharepoint-on-prem, content-migration

I recently migrated a site from 2007 to 2016 (both on-prem) using Sharegate. There was a web part on one of the pages that was not going to be compatible with 2016. That page is now broken in 2016 because of that web part

> Sorry, something went wrong. Could not load file or assembly 'webpart name, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=abcdef' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

I want to just edit the page and delete the broken web part but adding the edit URL to the page or adding ?content=1 is not working, I still have the error message. I also tried uploading the old web part files to the 2016 Web Part Gallery (didn't really think that would work).

How do I remove the web part reference in the 2016 version?

Comment: Note sure if this will work with 2016, but you could try to add `?contents=1` at the end of the link. Source: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7225/get-a-list-of-the-webparts-on-a-page

Comment: @douvillema Thanks for the suggestion already tried that with no luck

Comment: My bad, I didn't saw that you tried the `?content=1`. Nevermind!

Answer (score 4):

The `?contents=1` is working properly in SharePoint 2016

```
https://siteURL/pagename.aspx?contents=1
```

**But in your case,** I think you need to remove the WSP solution that contains this web part from the farm as the following:

**Retract & Remove the WSP solution**

```
Uninstall-SPSolution -Identity contoso_solution.wsp
```

After retracting the wsp solution, remove it.

```
Remove-SPSolution -Identity contoso_solution.wsp
```

> For more details check [UNINSTALL A SHAREPOINT (WSP) SOLUTION PACKAGE](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/20/how-to-retractremove-sharepoint-2010-solution-package-the-wsp-file/)

After that, you should go back to your page that should be opened properly, then remove the broken web part.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However the solution was not added at a farm level - just copied over from migration from site to site

Comment: try to redeploy it again manually, and make sure the custom dll files have been moved to the bin of web application check [How to install and deploy a SharePoint (WSP) Solution Package using PowerShell](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/20/how-to-deploy-a-sharepoint-wsp-solution-package/)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the page menu from the list view. Select "Edit Properties". Scroll to the bottom and click the "Open Web Part Page in maintenance view" link.

On that page you will see a list of web parts and you can **Close**, **Reset**, **Delete**, **Go back to Web Part Page**, or **Switch to Personal View**.

I normally either reset or delete the Web Part to correct any issues.
the URL is ../_layouts/15/spcontent.aspx?url=

Comment: It is the same as - https://siteURL/pagename.aspx?contents=1